# Need to have meta scraper or link preview in my reactJs page

Tags: reactjs

I need to display a preview card for the links, just like it is in the attached Screenshot. Here i have used Microlink and that is paid. tried react-tiny-link also. can anyone pls suggest me free packages for previewing links or meta scraping in ReactJS.

image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn2b7.png [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn2b7.png)

Comment: Hi @Anjan J Kumar I am the maintainer of react-tiny-link, please let me know if you need any implementation help for your project.Please feel free to use react-tiny-link for your production purpose as the library is licensed under MIT license.

Comment: Hey, the call is failing in my server. when url is passed the page goes blank

Comment: Hi @Anjan J Kumar , it would be great if you can provide the steps to reproduce on some sandbox environment like  https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @WinHtaikAung https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rhodes-ur2si?file=/src/App.js here it's working totally fine and also it is working fine in my local server. but when we deployed it in live server (Amazon cloud9) it's going blank